# Wrap Grouped Data in DIV (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, sqlsrv

Here's my code as it stands:

```
$sqlc = "SELECT DISTINCT UserID, OrgID, OrgName, StateID, StateName FROM vw_AgentService WHERE UserID = " . $id . "ORDER BY StateID";
$stmtc = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlc );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$current_state = null;
while( $rowc = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtc, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    if ($rowc["StateID"] != $current_state) {
        $current_state = $rowc['StateID'];
        echo "<h4>".$rowc['StateName']."</h4>";
    }
    echo "<p>".$rowc['OrgName']."</p>";
};
```

The table from which I'm pulling data has a row for each Organization, which each contains a column identifying it's corresponding US State. The output displays the State once, and then lists all the Organizations within that State, like this:

```
<h4>Federal (non-State)</h4>
<p>Environmental Protection Agency<p>

<h4>Texas</h4>
<p>Texas Legislature</p>
<p>Texas Commission on Environmental Quality</p>
```

What I want, but haven't been able to figure out, is to wrap the State header and the list of Organizations in their own DIV so I can display them as columns as opposed to a straight list all the way down, like this:

```
<div class="StateOrgs">
<h4>Federal (non-State)</h4>
<p>Environmental Protection Agency<p>
</div>

<div class="StateOrgs">
<h4>Texas</h4>
<p>Texas Legislature</p>
<p>Texas Commission on Environmental Quality</p>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Had to write myself a little table so I could visualize the whole story you are trying to tell. Rewrote my answer to better fit what you are trying to do. You need an inner query that is conditional (edit it if it needs a little tweaking but you get the idea).

```
while( $rowc = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtc, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
if ($rowc["StateID"] != $current_state) {
    $current_state = $rowc['StateID'];
    echo "<div class='StateOrgs'>";
    echo "<h4>".$rowc['StateName']."</h4>";
    while($innerqry = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtc, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
       if($innerqry['StateID']==$current_state){
       echo "<p>".$innerqry['OrgName']."</p>";}
       }
    echo "</div>
    }
};
```

This is what I had to type out to visualize what you are trying to do:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT UserID, OrgID, OrgName, StateID, StateName 
 FROM vw_AgentService WHERE UserID = " . $id . "ORDER BY StateID

          stateid    statename
 org 5    fed001     Federal
 org 3    fed001     Federal
 org 1    mid001     Maryland
 org 4    mid001     Maryland
 org 2    tid002     Tennesee

 <div>
 <h4>Fed</h4>
 <p>org 5</p>
 <p>org 3</p>
 </div>

 <div>
 <h4>Maryland</h4>
 <p>org 1</p>
 <p>org 4</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is not only does it remove duplicate State Names (which I want), but it limits the list of Orgs to just one, when some States contain multiple.

Comment: Edited answer to try to address those two things you're looking for. Edited it a few times actually because I kept finding typos. It probably wont be perfect, but I think it'll give you an idea what you gotta do.